# set auto_incremented primary key explicitly while inserting the record in JDO

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Enity primary key is an auto_incrimented ID in JDO

```
@Persistent(primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

When I am inserting any record, it's primary key ID is being set implicitly as auto_incremented.

I have a requirement in which I want set this ID (PK) using `setter(setId())` explicitly while inserting the record.

Can we do this?

Comment: Can't you remove `, valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY` ?

Comment: No we can not remove because its ok rest of the record, I have the specific case in which I want to set using setter.

Comment: Have you tried saving the object by `makePersistent()` then set the id, then `makePersistent()` again ?

Comment: I have tried with first setting the IDs then makePersistentAll I have a list of records. I need to try this..

Comment: You set strategy as IDENTITY which says "datastore should set this", then you say you want to set it yourself. You can have one or the other; they are mutually incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As comments say, you either use IDENTITY strategy (so its set by the datastore), or you set it yourself. You can't have both

Comment: Thanks, but there should be something like this because it might be useful in some cases.

Comment: @WavizTeam, I totally agree.